# Push for multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggeling with my multidimensional array. I actually have done research for  a few hours but couldn't find anything helpful.

I have a **multidimensional array** which looks like this:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 0],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1, 1],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 2],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 0],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 5, 2]
];
```

Now I want to add something to the array with push like:

---

```
locations.push( DATA HERE ); // 'Cronulla Beach 2', -34.028249, 151.157507, 8, 7
```

Which should look like this at the end:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 0],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1, 1],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, 2],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, 0],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 5, 2],
  ['Cronulla Beach 2', -34.028249, 151.157507, 8, 7]
];
```

---

Note: I need an array, so it doesn't help me if it is a solution with an object.

Preferably the solution should also work if the array is still empty like `locations[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the contents in another array and push that into your `locations` array, like

```
locations.push(['Cronulla Beach 2', -34.028249, 151.157507, 8, 7]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a multidimensional array is just an array of arrays, and you can create a new array by just placing a list of objects in square brackets, you can do this:

```
 locations.push(['Cronulla Beach 2', -34.028249, 151.157507, 8, 7]);
```

To access or edit an existing location, use its index:

```
 var location = locations[0];
 console.log(location);
 locations[0][0] = "Bomba Beach"; // change name of first location
 locations[0][1] = -30.2; // change latitude of first location
```